# Use of preposition 'in'

Tags: grammar

> (1) The fact is that over the past two decades India has been busy claiming "rising ","leading" and major power status, with its impressive economic rise between the mid-1990s and the mid-2010s.

> (2) The United States has successfully tested two Lockheed Martin hypersonic missiles, amid growing concerns that Russia and China have had more success developing their own hypersonic weapons.

This is a news paper extract. Here in this two sentences, it seem to me that the preposition 'in' should be used between 'busy' and 'claiming' in first sentence and between "success" and "developing" in second sentence.

https://www.abc.net.au/news/2022-07-14/hypersonic-weapons-test-lockheed-martin-successful/101237332

I have already seen this type sentences in various editorials where prepositions are not used and I don't know why??

Are these sentences grammatically correct without using 'in' between 'busy' and 'claiming' and between "succes" and "developing"???

Is it ok to lapse the preposition here??? Is it correct??

Comment: _Busy [doing something]_ is a perfectly idiomatic usage.

Answer (score 1):

As to (1):

> X has been busy doing Y.

is a perfectly natural usage. It would be understood by any fluent speaker. It is commonly used. Indeed I would say that it is significantly **more** natural nd common than

> X has been busy **in** doing Y.

As to (2)

> X has had success developing Y.

is also a thoroughly natural and common usage. The word "in" is not at all needed, and is often not used in such a construction.

Comment: David Siegel@ If I used 'in' between them, then is it right???

Comment: @Ansh
 Using "in" is not wrong. But it is no more riht thsn not using it, and for sentences like (1) not using it is probably better.